# wave or curve effect in bottom tab react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to make the bottom tabs with a custom style. I have to achieve something like this ->

[image]

I can only do a basic structure by styling it with react-native-bottom-tabs

this is my result so far-> [image]

but I can't get it, since the library I'm using, rn-wave-bottom-bar, is not very flexible with style changes and I would need some idea or help please!!!

**React-Native 0.70.6
react => 18.1.0**

Thank you

Comment: you should be looking at svg bottom tabs, and animations

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have seen some solutions where the design is done with svg, is there a particular library that you recommend? Thank you!

Comment: no, to be honest it's a big hassle

Comment: Thanks for the honesty, I'll be trying!

Comment: @GuidoGagliardini yes rn-wave-bottom-bar  this is the name of the lib that you can use  link  https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-wave-bottom-bar

Comment: @PankajSharma yes, i saw this package. I tried to try it, but it is not very customizable or at least I did not try it well, but I will try again. Thank you